# Get dict of sums per date from 2 lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have two lists of equal lengths, one with dates (YYYY-MM-DD) where some are repeating, and one with floats (both positive and negative). How would I get a dictionary object with the sum of floats corresponding to each unique date (sorted), in this format:

```
result_dict = {unique_date_1: float_sum_1, unique_date_2: float_sum_2, etc...}
```

My lists:

```
dates = [2013-06-22, 2009-07-09, 2016-07-09, 2009-07-09]
floats = [0.0, 0.8, -0.4, 0.1]
```

What I hope to get:

```
{2009-07-09: 0.9, 2013-06-22: 0.0, 2016-07-09: -0.4}
```

What I have tried so far:

```
unique_dates = set(dates)
sum_list = [sum(number) for number in floats]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd start with an empty result, then for each date/float pair, update the result. I'm using `defaultdict` so we don't have to mess around with checking if the date's been seen yet.

```
from collections import defaultdict
result = defaultdict(float)  # Default value of 0

for date, val in zip(dates, floats):
    result[date] += val
```

For the part of your question about being sorted, dicts aren't an ordered collection, but that doesn't stop you from iterating over them in order:

```
for date, float in sorted(result.items()):
    do_stuff_with_dates_in_order()
```

Or, if you don't want to call `sorted` every time:

```
from collection import OrderedDict
sorted_result = OrderedDict(sorted(result.items()))
```

Comment: `result[date] += float` should be `result[date] += val`

Comment: You should not use (suggest OP to use) names of built-in functions (like `"float"`) as variable names

Comment: Yes, thanks. Please see the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53622013/revisions) I posted in response to nicholishen's comment. It was a typo :)

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to use a `defaultdict` with `float` as the default factory. Then `zip` the lists and iterate over the keys and values whilst summing the values with the appropriate key.

```
from collections import defaultdict

dates = ['2013-06-22', '2009-07-09', '2016-07-09', '2009-07-09']
floats = [0.0, 0.8, -0.4, 0.1]

sum_dic = defaultdict(float)

for date, value in zip(dates, floats):
    sum_dic[date] += value
```

output

```
defaultdict(<class 'float'>, {'2013-06-22': 0.0, '2009-07-09': 0.9, '2016-07-09': -0.4})
```

You can also do it without importing defaultdict like this:

```
sum_dic = {}
for date, value in zip(dates, floats):
    sum_dic[date] = sum_dic.get(date, 0.0) + value
```